# Ionic 4 - How to keep the form with fixed height to prevent the submit button from rising when opening the keyboard?

Tags: html, css, angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

Ionic 4 - How to keep the form with fixed height to prevent the submit button from rising when opening the keyboard?

I would like to fix the submit button always in the starting position, at the bottom of the screen.

When I open the page the submit button is positioned at the bottom of the screen. I would like that when inserting email or password the button would continue at the bottom of the screen and the keyboard would open over it.

Can anybody help me?

[Interaction example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ageHT.gif)

HTML

```
<ion-header mode="md" translucent="true">
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-buttons slot="start">
      <ion-back-button text=""></ion-back-button>
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-toolbar>

  <ion-title>{{ 'loginEmail.title' | translate:params }}</ion-title>
</ion-header>
<ion-content padding>
  <br>
  <form [formGroup]="loginForm" (ngSubmit)="setLoginData()" style="height:auto !important">
    <ion-label class="form-label" position="fixed">{{ 'loginEmail.email' | translate:params }}</ion-label>
    <ion-input class="input" name="email" placeholder="{{ 'loginEmail.emailPlaceholder' | translate:params }}"
      type="email" formControlName="email"></ion-input>
    <br>
    <ion-label class="form-label" position="fixed">{{ 'loginEmail.password' | translate:params }}</ion-label>
    <ion-input class="input" name="password" placeholder="{{ 'loginEmail.passwordPlaceholder' | translate:params }}"
      type="password" formControlName="password"></ion-input>
    <div>
      <a routerLink="/register4" class="forgotPassword">{{ 'loginEmail.forgotPassword' | translate:params }}</a>
    </div>
    <ion-button class="signIn" size="large" type="submit" [disabled]="loading" style="
    margin-top: 360px;">
      <label class="label">{{ 'loginEmail.buttonLabel' | translate:params }}</label>
    </ion-button>
  </form>
</ion-content>
```

SCSS

```
ion-header::after {
    background-image: none;
    --ion-background-color: #f0f2f4;
}

ion-header {
    ion-toolbar {
        ion-buttons {
            ion-back-button {
                color: #48385c !important;
            }
            a {
                font-size: 25px;
                padding-top: 4px;
                width: 40px;
                padding-left: 20px;
            }
        }
        --ion-background-color: #f0f2f4;
    }

    ion-title {
        font-family: Rubik;
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: 500;
        font-size: 24px;
        line-height: 34px;
        color: #183657;
        background-color: #f0f2f4;
        padding: 20px 20px 0px 20px;
    }
}

ion-content {
    --ion-background-color: #f0f2f4;

    .title {
        font-family: Rubik;
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: 500;
        font-size: 24px;
        line-height: 30px;
        text-align: center;
        color: #183657;
    }

    .form {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        margin-left: 30px;
        margin-right: 30px;
    }

    .input {
        border: 1px solid #959393;
        width: 100%;
        height: 50px;
        -moz-border-radius: 50px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
        border-radius: 10px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }

    .has-focus.sc-ion-input-md-h {
        pointer-events: none;
        border: 2px solid #187ceb !important;
    }

    ion-button {
        text-transform: none;
        display: block;
        margin: 30px 0px 0px 0px;
        font-weight: 600;
        height: 50px;
        --border-radius: 10px;
        .label {
            font-size: 16px;
            padding-left: 15px;
        }
    }

    .signIn {
        --background: #187ceb;
        bottom: 20px !important;
        position: fixed;
        width: calc(100% - 30px);
    }
    .forgotPassword {
        font-family: Rubik;
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 16px;
        line-height: 22px;
        align-items: center;
        text-align: center;
        color: #183657;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    .signUp-label {
        font-family: Rubik;
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: normal;
        font-size: 16px;
        line-height: 22px;
        align-items: center;
        text-align: center;
        color: #183657;
    }

    .form-label {
        font-family: Rubik;
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: normal;
        font-size: 16px;
        line-height: 34px;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        color: #48385c;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried setting your ion-content height to 100%?

And the fact that you have the button margin set 360 from top is suspicious.

Consider putting this whole thing in an ion-grid.

Answer (score 0):

Try using css property
Position: absolute ;
And then place it on right place using top left right bottom property

Sorry for typos

Comment: You can tried edit question codes and write good answer. Please read how to write good answer? In help center.